# Why is my image pushed down when I put it inline with a span?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```html
    <div>
        <img src="../Resources/css/img/IOlogo.png" style="height:16px;">
        <span style="vertical-align:top;"> Unlimited Access</span>
    </div>
```

The image is displaying about 5 pixels lower than the text. It slightly below the bottom boundary of the div.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle or the `IOlogo.png` image?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Yes I posted this way to make it easier. I have a stylesheet dedicated for custom css.

Comment: @AndrewMcCracken ah I see then no worries - will remove my comment :)

Answer (score 0):

You ave given `vertical-algin:top` only to the span. The deafult value of the vertical align is baseline.so image will align baseline. Try vertical-algin:top for the both image and span.

```css
img,span{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="../Resources/css/img/IOlogo.png" style="height:16px;">
    <span> Unlimited Access</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `display: block; float: left;` instead of `vertical-align:top;` will do the same thing.

Comment: @BazzyTK Yes it will result the same